# HTML: set element size relative to parent when position is absolute

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to do it?

If I do it like this:

```
<div id="container" style="width:500px;">
    <div id="content" style="position:absolute;width:100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the content div will have the width of the browser window, instead of the 500px from the parent container div.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Always give **position:relative** to the `parent` if it's `child` have **position:absolute;**. Give **position:relative** to your `#container` DIV. Write like this:

```
<div id="container" style="width:500px;position:relative">
    <div id="content" style="position:absolute;width:100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, what if an img inside the content div also needs to have position:absolute and width:100%?

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `position` of #container to `relative`. [Check out this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YDrpa/) for a demo.